# Access variable in function, outside class without error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, function, variables, scope

I have a small program where a user enters their name, 3 dots come up to symbolize loading, and then it outputs their name in a message.

The following, without loading function, works fine

```
class Item
  puts "Enter name"

  def name
    @username = $stdin.gets.chomp  
  end
end

item = Item.new

puts "Thankyou #{item.name}" #=> returns name entered
```

Once I add the loading function like such:

```
class Item
  puts "Enter name"

  def name
    @username = $stdin.gets.chomp  
    loading
  end
  def loading
    (0..2).each do |x|
      puts "."
    end
  end
end

item = Item.new

puts "Thankyou #{item.name}" #=> returns (0..2)
```

Instead of returning the name in the thankyou message, it returns (0..2), somehow calling the "loading" function in the "name" function messed it up. I assume the best way would to be able to access the "username" variable within the "name" function? I heard global variables are bad but I'm not really sure how to do them anyway. So what do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the value of `@username` after `loading`:

```
def name
  @username = $stdin.gets.chomp
  loading
  @username
end
```

Functions in Ruby by default return the result of their last statement, with `name` invoking `loading`:

```
def name
  @username = $stdin.gets.chomp
  return loading
end

def loading
  return (0..2).each ...
end
```

`name` returns the value it gets from `loading`, that returns the value it gets from `each`, which is the collection it was called on -- `(0..2)`.

Comment: Thank you, much easier than I thought!